# Transform a string such as (0&(1|0)|1) & (0|1) into it's corresponding truth value

Tags: c++, parsing

I found this on an interview forum and thought it was an interesting question. Is there any simple way to accomplish this task in C++? For example, suppose we have the function declaration:

```
bool _transform(string x); 
/* x is a combination of (, ), 0, 1, &, and | such that all expressions 
   start with a open and ending brace, and the function evaluates the 
   strings actual truth value 
*/
```

Is there any efficient and relatively simple way to do this? I thought of recursively closing in on parentheses, but the problem just seems difficult.

Comment: Can you assume the string is a valid expression? I'm pretty sure that will change the implementation quite a bit.

Comment: @Human Sorry for not clarifying but yes, the string will always be valid and error-checking is not (presumably) required. For simplicity sake I'll just say that the expression is always of the correct form.

Comment: It's just a rather simple exercise in expression parsing and evaluation, with logical operators instead of arithmetic ones. Trivial really. Look up 'recursive descent expression parsing' or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. @Human These algorithms can detect invalid input: it doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, you're right. I figured an implementation of one would be a bit simpler without any error handling.

Comment: Recursion's good... Just have a function that returns both a 0/1 outcome and the next character position where the calling context needs to continue.  You need to decide if there'll be precedence - e.g. is 1|0&1 to or then and, or and then or.

Comment: The simplest algorithm I know for this is Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm. It should be very straightforward to implement it given that every token is a single character long.

Comment: @EJP Write your comment as an answer. The answer need not be code for this question. +1

Comment: If you want an overkill solution, I think you can make a context-free grammar that works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a rather simple exercise in expression parsing and evaluation, with logical operators instead of arithmetic ones. Trivial really. Look up 'recursive descent expression parsing' or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. Warning: there are many home-grown and other near-equivalents of the latter, and most of them have subtle bugs or non-linear performance. Use the source.

NB the value of the expression in your title is `1.`

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution to this problem is a stack-based parser. [Recursive descent would be overkill.]

```
For each character in the string
  If it's a value (0 1)
    If top of stack is an operator
      Pop operator and value, evaluate
    Push value on the stack
  If it's an operator (&|) push it on the stack
  If it's a left parenthesis push it on the stack
  If it's a right parenthesis pop the value and the LP, push the value
At end, pop the value off the stack.
```

More code needed to handle errors gracefully, but you get the idea. It also ignores precedence.

This concept is really easy to extend to any kind of arithmetic expression, but you need to handle precedence to get the right answers. Effectively this transforms the expression from infix to postfix notation, and evaluates on the fly.

Comment: That's not quite right... with your current logic "1&0" -> "push [1]", "pop 2 values" - oops.

Comment: @TonyD: Glad someone was watching. Been a while since I did one of these. See edits.

Comment: looks great for when precedence support's not needed (+1).